# How do I make Windows spin down my external HDD before cutting power to it when I shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, shutdown

Whenever I shutdown my laptop, my external HDD make a loud "click" sound when the power is cut. Even if the hard drive is idle, it spins up for a few seconds before being forcibly turned off without spinning down. It's connected directly to my laptop (not using a hub) with a Sabrent USB HDD enclosure.

Comment: It's working as designed.

Comment: It sounds like it's autoparking the heads. I would not try to stop that.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to deal with this is to right-click the icon in the system tray (near the clock) that is used to eject drives, and eject the USB drive. It will ask the USB device to normally shut down. Do note, the same system should be used automatically during shutdown, so you may hear the same spinning up, but in case it isn't, then doing a manual eject on the USB drive is what you're after.

It is likely, that the drive itself is just parking its head. The drive has a small battery (capacitor) that gives it enough power to safely spin up the drive, and move the head to a parked state so it is ready for transport.